# Can a tank attack across water within the same space (Germany to UK)?

Tags: axis-and-allies

When there is a space that has one country's tank (Germany for example) and the same space on the board contains water between the enemy's land (UK for example), can the Germany tank attack UK...even though there is water between the two contries but they are in the same space? Or does the tank have to be transported even though it is in the same space?

Comment: I don't ever recall the English Channel `freezing over` like that in 1940; Hitler would have loved it of course, as would Napoleon, Phillip II, and even Caesar and William `The Bastard` (before Hastings).

Comment: What do you mean 'same space'?  Germany and the UK are two different spaces, so they're not in the same space...

Answer (score 9):

Here's the snippet of map we're talking about:

[image: England and Germany in the Axis & Allies map]

There are three spaces of interest here:

1. England (a land zone)
2. The water surrounding England (a sea zone)
3. Western Europe (a land zone)

These are three separate spaces, and must be passed through in turn; Western Europe is *not* adjacent to England. **You can't just jump from Western Europe to England, you need to pass through the sea zone on the way there.** Unfortunately, tanks can't enter sea zones except by boarding a transport.

So getting a tank from Western Europe to England looks like this:

1. A German Tank starts in Western Europe. It can't enter the sea zone, because it's a tank.
2. Germany has a transport in the sea zone surrounding England, and *there are no Allied sea units in that zone.*
3. Tank boards transport, entering the sea zone in the only way it can.
4. Tank exits transport onto England, and gets involved in the combat there.

Comment: Hmm, does that imply Ireland is a seperate zone?

Comment: @TimLymington Isn't Ireland neutral? It's colored like Sweden on the map.

Comment: @TimLymington yes, Ireland is an entirely separate zone. It's a neutral country, like Spain. It's also wholly useless; England doesn't need it, and Germany doesn't want it either: it's just as far from England as Western Europe is.

Answer (score 2):

A tank has to be carried over "water" by a transport. From there, it can debark on any "land" square adjacent to the transport's "stopping" square.

But the tank unit can't traverse water square by itself (without a transport).